# How to count number of associated records, when association has composite primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a `customers` table, and an associated `orders` table, I want to count the number of orders made per customer.

However, the `orders` table has a composite primary key. Here are the schemas and the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
    name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Joe');
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Jane');

CREATE TABLE orders (
    customer_name TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES customers (name),
    section_id INT NOT NULL,
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_name, section_id, item_id)
);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('Joe', 1, 100);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('Joe', 1, 101);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('Joe', 2, 110);
```

There are two customers: Joe (with 3 orders) and Jane (with no orders).

This query...

```sql
SELECT customers.*,
  COUNT((orders.section_id, orders.item_id)) AS num_orders
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders
  ON customers.name = orders.customer_name
GROUP BY customers.name;
```

...correctly counts that Joe has 3 orders, but incorrectly counts that Jane has 1 order (she actually has 0).

That's because `COUNT((orders.section_id, orders.item_id))` produces 1. Even though section_id and item_id are both NULL, the tuple expression `(NULL, NULL)` is not considered NULL.

How do I properly query the orders count in the face of composite primary keys?

Comment: Why do you want to count on both: `section_id` and `item_id`?

Comment: I want to count on both fields because the orders table's primary key is a composite of (customer_name, section_id, item_id). Counting on just item_id for example produces incorrect results because it does not uniquely identify a single order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you want to count on both fields: `section_id` and `item_id`...

I'd suggest to provide simple experiment:

```
SELECT (NULL, NULL) result
-- produces: (,)
```

So, when you use id with `COUNT`, it have to return `1` - as it's NOT `NULL`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL) result
-- produces: NULL
```

So, when you use id with `COUNT`, it have to return `0` - as it's `NULL`.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b84e005e465717d0e60216f72625da0)

As to me, it's enough to use `COUNT(item_id)` or `COUNT(section_id)`, as both can NOT be `null`. So...

```
SELECT c.*,
  COUNT(o.section_id) AS num_orders
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o
  ON c.name = o.customer_name
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Unless... you want to get distinct sections/items in each order of specific customer.

```
SELECT c.*,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.section_id) AS num_sections,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.item_id) AS num_items
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o
  ON c.name = o.customer_name
GROUP BY c.name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c1a0cc94a9df81877bee83be0a6516ba)

Comment: I want to count on both fields because the `orders` table's primary key is a composite of (customer_name, section_id, item_id). Counting on just item_id for example produces incorrect results because it does not uniquely identify a single order.

Answer (score 0):

Count `orders.customer_name`, that's the one that's guaranteed not to be `NULL` if there was a join partner row as it's used in the `ON` clause with `=`.

```
SELECT customers.*,
       count(orders.customer_name) AS num_orders
       FROM customers
            LEFT JOIN orders
                      ON customers.name = orders.customer_name
       GROUP BY customers.name;
```